# Laravel 8 test case not sending request body

Tags: testing, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 application and it works perfectly. I want to write unit tests that test my endpoints. I have a login endpoint that works great when I use postman and Javascript. NO matter what I send to the endpoint I always get a valid JSON message.

I am running tests and during the tests something weird happens. I get an error that the application returns a 204 HTTP response code with means no content. This implies that the request body is not being send to the backend.

My test looks like this:

```
$loginRequestDto = ['email' => 'invalid@test.nl', 'password' => 'test', 'clientUuid' => 'abcd1234'];

    $response = $this->json(
        'POST',
        route('api.login'),
        $loginRequestDto
    );

    $response = $response->assertOk()->decodeResponseJson();
```

I do the `$this->json` and send the $loginRequestDto which is an array. For some really really weird reason a call is done to the endpoint (and is called, I can see that in the log) however no request body is being sent.

How do you send a request body to an endpoint?